# How i display specific page for specidfic logged in user in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

i want to display specific tasks for specific people....like if raj is logged in then tasks of raj should display not others.
so please give me some solution...

views.py(home fn)

```
def home(request):
   username=request.session['username']
   for username in username:
      todo_items=TODO.objects.all().order_by("-created_date")
      return render(request,'main/index.html', 
                                   {'todo_items':todo_items,'username':username})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class TODO(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_date=models.DateTimeField()
    text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way with request.user

```
def home(request):
    todo_items=TODO.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("-created_date")
    return render(request,'main/index.html', 
                                   {'todo_items':todo_items,})
```

and username in any template is available by `request.user.username`

Comment: still i'm getting error (my all tasks not displaing )  can  i send my code to you???

Comment: i have created to-doapp  and  when i'm putting  above code i'm not getting any error but i lost every  tasks which i was displaying them in index.html

Comment: the user should be logged in and should have created some data

Comment: still it is not displaying,i wanna show you my code(index.html).. because it's too long so i can't put it here